# Timed out waiting 5200 milliseconds for property data to be updated for property

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I setup to record audio in my apps like this:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
}
err = nil;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
self.recordSetting = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[_recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[_recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithFloat:kMusicSampleRate] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[_recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[_recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

Everything run correctly in iphone 4, 4s and 5. But some 5s has this error:

```
ERROR:    13:57:30.310 [tid 0x102dd8000] [298]: timed out waiting 5200 milliseconds for property data to be updated for property [goin/glob/0] (property was updated = 0, error = 0)
EXCEPTION: 13:57:30.311 [tid 0x102dd8000] [673]: didStartResult: "Error waiting to receive kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceIsRunning property notification."
EXCEPTION: 13:57:30.312 [tid 0x102dd8000] [2362]: theError: "error starting IO on the active device"
ERROR:     [0x102dd8000] 176: error 'what'
WARNING:   [0x102dd8000] >aq> 1594: aq@0x146938600: ConvertInput using invalid anchor time
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, would love to know how did you resolve this issue...